# Undefined symbol _UnitySendMessage

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, objective-c++, armv7

Define a method in the .mm file

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C"{
#endif
    extern void UnitySendMessage(const char* obj, const char* method, const char* msg) __attribute__ ((weak));;
    extern NSString* _CreateNSString (const char* string);
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif

@interface UnityAdapter ()
...
```

Called in `@implementation UnityAdapter()`

```
UnitySendMessage("PottingMobile", "bannerDidLoadAd", "");
```

I need help solving the following error:

```
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'FBSDKCoreKit'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_UnitySendMessage", referenced from:
      -[UnityAdapter bannerDidLoadAd] in UnityAdapter.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when i don't use `UnitySendMessage` method， everthing is ok.

I want to write a framework for bridging unit and iOS projects. When I use it in a unit packaged project, no problem. When I put the bridging file into my own framework, I will report an error. There is nothing in the framework project. Do I need to integrate unit's lib? If so, how to integrate? Can you give me a website? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please update the Chinese description with English, so it will be more convenient for everyone to understand.

Comment: it seems not to have found your FBSDKCoreKit - which sounds like facebook

Comment: No I believe it's `libiPhone-lib.a` which is provided by Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is currently doing this with their [library feature](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/06/17/add-features-powered-by-unity-to-native-mobile-apps).

You can look at their solution.

If you need a solution now: Have a look at https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity. It's all automated and a good starting point, but missing the library feature.
This project shows how to make an actual library: https://github.com/forestlin1212/unity-ios-framework (But for an older Unity version and not automated)